# Virtualbox guest additions work only partially

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I am running debian inside virtual box, and installed Guest Additions for it. They worked well, I did something and now clipboard works but drag and drop doesn't (yes it is turned on)

I have tried isntalling Guest Additions over again, but with no luck(yes I rebooted)

My de is gdm/gnome. OS is debian. Host is windows.

Comment: You can try reinstalling Virtual Box. Back up the guest machine. Uninstall Virtual Box, restart, install the newest version of Virtual Box, restart again, restore your guest machine and test

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Wayland. I switched to X11 now it works well